# Clearing Activity Stack on Intent Start

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I have an app that I'm writing that starts with an initial Login/Create New Account splash screen. In onCreate it checks my SharedPreferences to see if user credentials are stored. If they are the activity launches an intent to the main activity skipping the login/create process.

```
if (haveCredentials()) {
    Intent i = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    startActivity(i);
}
```

I don't want the user to be able to go back to the splash screen. As you can see I'm trying the `CLEAR_TOP` Intent flag as suggested by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16478625/android-clear-activity-history) but it doesn't seem to be working. Not sure what I'm missing.

**Current State of the Activity Stack**

`SplashActivity->MainActivity`

**Desired State of the Stack**

`MainActivity`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried finishing the current activity?

```
if (haveCredentials()) {
    Intent i = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    startActivity(i);
    finish(); //add this!
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use `finish()` after `startActivity()`, so that when back button is pressed the previous activity will not be shown.