# onBackPressed with viewpager activity and fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments

i have a viewpager activity containing fragment named OneFragment.

The Onefragment contains a recyclerview,on items click a fragment called DescriptionFragment opens.

This is how i opened the DescriptionFragment from the Adapter:

```
 Fragment descriptionFragment = new DescriptionFragment ();
                FragmentTransaction transaction = mContext.beginTransaction();
                transaction.replace(R.id.framelayout, descriptionFragment).addToBackStack(null).commit();
```

**Problem:** 
When i click on backpress button the app finishes.

I want on backpress to close the DescriptionFragment and return back to the OneFragment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add fragment to stack while comitting a transaction like this

```
transaction.addToBackStack(OneFragment.getClass().getName);
```

and your transaction code should look somrething like this

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction transaction= fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
transaction.replace(..............);
transaction.addToBackStack(null);
transaction.commit();
```

Comment: I used(OneFragment.class.getName()) but still getting same result

Comment: Instead of mContext.beginTransactiin() try adding fragmentManager.beginTransaction()

Comment: It worked i was using getChildFragmentManager i changed to FragmentMangaer

Comment: Please one more question:

How to handle the on resume method?
Because when i am resuming the app it restarts it  doesn t resume

Comment: Everytime either you open app or resume ,onResume method is called. What is exactly the issue you are facing?

Comment: When i pause the app and then resume it..the app relaunches from 0..i want the app resume my OneFragment

Comment: i think it is realted to savedInsatance state of fragment and activity,
this might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6337217/how-to-return-to-the-latest-launched-activity-when-re-launching-application-afte

Comment: Thanks it worked on HomeButton press not the backbutton 
any idea?

Comment: when you press back button the onDestroy method is called and now when you come back there wont be any savedInsatanceState from which the activity can be resumed.

Comment: Big Thank for help!