# After pressing home button saving the state of Activity

Tags: android, state

I have two activities, `Activity1` and `Activity2`. `Activity1` is launcher activity which starts at the beginning. Now when I'm pressing Home button from `activity2` and again opening the app from all apps then `Activity1` is opening. I want to open the same activity that was opened at the time of pressing the home button. I need to save state of `activity2`, but how I don't have any clue.

I looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5086985/maintaining-application-state-in-android) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4783960/call-method-when-home-button-pressed-on-android) but still I didn't got the clear picture on how to do this. Please help me as I'm new to android.

Comment: what you are trying to do should work by default. the first link you posted should help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you pressed "home" button, your activity goes to `onPause()`.

So I personally recommend you to override the `onPause()` method which can not only handle the  "home" button pressed but also other circumstances.

In your case, it is only `onPause()` and `onResume()` related, so you can try put the state into `SharedPreferences` or Internal/External storage.

say:

in your `onPause()` method, do something like:

```
// Use Shared Preferences to save data
SharedPreferences previewSizePref = getSharedPreferences("PREF",MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor prefEditor = previewSizePref.edit();
prefEditor.putInt("x", somethingA);
prefEditor.putInt("y", somethingB);
prefEditor.commit();
```

and in your `onResume()`, retrieve the saved data like:

```
SharedPreferences previewSizePref = getSharedPreferences("PREF",MODE_PRIVATE);
if (previewSizePref.contains("x") && previewSizePref.contains("y")) {
    //your saved data exists, do something
} else {
    // handle the circumstances that the saved data doesn't exist
}
```

For saving state in `onPause()` and restore in `onResume()` you can have a look at this answer:

[Saving Activity State in the onPause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8410259/saving-activity-state-in-the-onpause)

And for SharedPreferences, you can have a look at API document: [Data Storage - Shared Preferences](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref)

Comment: Do I need to override `onResume()` also?

Comment: @Jai Yes, you need to override `onResume()` to restore your activity state.

Comment: @Jai ah, please w8 a minute, I'm updating my answer, I found in your case the reference I gave is not suitable.

Comment: @Jai Please check the updated answer, sorry if my previous answer made you confused.

Comment: If we resume application after pressing home button then by default it resumes the left activity state. Am I right?

Comment: @Jai It will go via `onResume()`. Have you checked the Activity Lifecycle diagram? it's an easier way to understand the activity lifecycle: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html

Answer (score 0):

What you're describing should be standard for behaviour for Android, and if it isn't doing what you describe then you've probably overwritten this behaviour somewhere else, probably in your manifest.

If you create a new Android application and make a simple two page app, with Activity A as the launcher and Activity B as the second page, then your manifest will look like the following and the app will display the behaviour you describe.

```
<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".ActivityA"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".ActivityB"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
    </activity>
</application>
```

Double check that your manifest looks similar to this- Activity B has no flags and is just a declaration that it exists in your manifest.